# Tableless Model - NoMethodError on creating object from form params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I get this error when I try to save my tableless model using the form provided parameters:

[image: error message]

User is my devise model. I don't know where the error comes from, and what the reason is. I shouldn't cast date or whatever.

I created the tableless model using the [ActiveRecord Tableless](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless) gem:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_no_table

  column :start_date, :date
  column :end_date, :date
  column :smart, :boolean
end
```

My form:

```
  <%= form_for @search, url: {controller: 'search', action: 'search'} do |s| %>
        <%= s.hidden_field :smart, :value => false %>

      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group'>
            <%= s.text_field :start_date, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group'>
            <%= s.text_field :end_date, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
        <%= button_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

My controller where I get the error:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @search = Search.new(search_params)

    puts params
    puts @search.as_json.to_s
  end

  private
  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :smart)
  end
end
```

I'm using a model for my form because I want it to have many-to-one association to other models in the future.

## Update

As *alexcavalli* pointed out, this is an issue with ActiveRecord Tableless gem. The ticket can be found [here](https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless/issues/22#issuecomment-67742177).

Comment: Is this error showing when accessing `search` page, or after submitting the form?

Comment: On form submit I call the search method. So on submitting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `from_user` part of that method name is unrelated to devise. It's just an ActiveRecord method.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord/Type/Value:type_cast_from_user

There's an open issue with that Tableless gem and Rails 4.2
https://github.com/softace/activerecord-tableless/issues/22#issuecomment-67742177

Or there's also some information that it might be due to the Postgres adapter

> This issue still exists when using Postgresql (pg) adapter. I get errors when using :string. Have been able to work around this by using :varchar

You might be better off filing a bug report there and/or trying a slightly older version of Rails. Good luck!